# Visualstudio generated Webservice throws exception (no code written yet)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asmx

A new, empty Visualstudio project, with only auto-generated code, throws an exception, when trying to call the webservice, from that webservices own description page.

I had this weird problem, that I project, that worked fine, when I used it last time, suddenly stopped working (no change in between) when I opened it 2 Months later. I couldn't figure out, what the cause was, so I tryed to recreate it in a simpler fassion.

This is the not working example, without a single line of handwritten code, all created by visualstudio.

Here's what I did to recreate the problem.

I use Visualstudio 2015
I created a new Project -> Web -> ASP.NET -> Web API.
I added a empty folder, called "services"
I Rightclicked on the folder -> Add -> (Webservice Asmx)

a new demopage was created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ProjektName.Services
{
    /// <summary>

    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class getUrl : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

when I start call the page, the Webservice self description page opens.

These are not actual screenshots because my Visual Studio is in a different language. (They are just used to explain my point).

I use windows 10 and use the lates Chrome and firefox browsers.
/HelloWorld_files/image004.jpg[image: some random image from the internet]
[image: some random image from the internet]

Now, when I hit the button, I get a "Server Error in '/' Application." "The resource cannot be found."

The error message looks something like this:
https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/fileadmin/community/Screenshots/How_to_Fix_the_Error_in_application_Windows_Server_error/404.jpg

I haven't written a single line of code, it was all generated by Visal Studio.
If I give the project to a coworker, it doesn't work on his pc as well.

What do I miss?

Comment: "These are not actual screenshots" is a problem. The devil is in the details.

Comment: asmx is way, way beyond it's lifecycle. Invest in WebAPI or WCF instead.

Comment: the WebAPI didn't work, so I switched to ASMX

Comment: "so I switched ..." - and now you have 2 problems (-:   Seriously, ASMX is End-Of-Life stuff, forget it.

Comment: your solution worked, thank you, now there's only one problem^^ left :) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ignore rule:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Services/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");  // add this line

    ....
}
```

---

But it looks like you are doing something 'Tutorial'. Are you sure you want to invest in ASMX technology?